# I'm trying to implementation Facebook SDK using Firebase but I keep getting an error on the when I copy this code in the correct spot

Tags: flutter

```
    dependencies {
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
        dependencies {

            // Import the Firebase BoM

            implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.1')


            // Add the dependency for the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics

            // When using the BoM, don't specify versions in Firebase dependencies

            implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'


            // Add the dependencies for any other desired Firebase products

            // https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available-libraries
            implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:latest.release'
        }



    }
```

```dart
    import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
    import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';


     abstract class AuthBase{
       User get currentUser;
       Stream<User> authStateChanges();
       Future<User>signInAnonymously();
       Future<User> signInWithGoogle();
       Future<void>signOut();
     }


    class Auth implements AuthBase {

      final _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

      Stream<User> authStateChanges() => _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges();

      @override
      User get currentUser => _firebaseAuth.currentUser;

      @override
      Future<User> signInAnonymously() async {
        final userCredential = await _firebaseAuth.signInAnonymously();
        return userCredential.user;
      }

      @override
      Future<User> signInWithGoogle() async{
        final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
        final googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
        if(googleUser !=null) {
          final googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
          if (googleAuth.idToken != null) {
            final userCredential = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(
                GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
                  idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
                  accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
                ));
            return userCredential.user;
          } else {
            throw FirebaseAuthException(
              code:'ERROR_MISSING_GOOGLE_ID_TOKEN',
                message:'Missing Google ID Token',
            );
          }
        }
        else {
          throw FirebaseAuthException(
            code: 'ERROR_ABORTED_BY_USER',
            message: 'Sign in aborted by user'

        );
        }
      }

      Future<User> signInWithFacebook() async{
        final fb = FacebookLogin();

      }

      @override
      Future<void> signOut() async {
        final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
        await googleSignIn.signOut();
        await _firebaseAuth.signOut();
        // TODO: implement signOut
        throw UnimplementedError();
      }
    }
```

`][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuOEj.png)][1][I'm trying to implement facebook SDK into my project.I have followed all of the steps up to this point and you can find the link below but I'm still getting an error  When I copied this code in to the Main activity page.What am I doing wrong?I posted my auth.dart file and the dependencies as well

```kotlin
package com.example.time_trackerpractice

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger;

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
}
```

[image]

Comment: Show me this file > lib/services/auth.dart

Comment: Can you add list of dependencies in your `build.gradle` file?

Comment: @fartem i posted the dependencies in the css box.

Comment: Are you sure that `FacebookLogin` exists?

Comment: @fartem it doesn't yet I'm trying to install facebook sdk first so that I can run it thats my problem

Comment: @Felipe Vergara I posted my the auth.dart file in the html code box

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you have ([see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiwQ5.png)) its because you don't have any flutter packages related to facebook auth.

In this line of your code you are try instance a FacebookLogin, but doesn't exits any import related to facebook login.

```
final fb = FacebookLogin();
```

You can use this package to facebook login ([flutter_facebook_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_auth)), and replace your inside code of your function **signInWithFacebook** for this:

```
Future<User> signInWithFacebook() async {
    final result = await FacebookAuth.instance
          .login(permissions: ['email', 'public_profile']);
    final accessToken = result.accessToken;
    final credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(accessToken.token);
    userCredential = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    return userCredential.user
}
```